# Duplicate web services

Tags: web-services, wcf, iis

I am in situation I have two projects in a solution,

> myCompany.Utilities
>
> myCompany.InternalWebSerivces (accessible by any authenticated domain
>   users)

Now we are adding another product-B to our company, which going to be integrated with current product-A but COULD be hosted on a different domain.

I need to make sure my "InternalWebSerivces" accessible by Product-B too without changing the way product-A works.

Product-B may use client certificate authentication, restricted to a specific user, or have a different bindings to InternalWebSerivces.

Even though InternalWebSerivces is just sort of interface with real logic in utilities project, should I duplicate it and add another project with same web services, this way we can have two same web services with different configrations (web.config).

I am not really a expert when it comes to web services, but I did worked with them a lot. Please share you expert knowledge on best way please, is duplicating web services my only resort ?

Comment: Did the answer help?

Comment: @Wibbler i hope yes, but am yet to test your proposal, I am accepting your answer for now and will update with results, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your web service has internal code relating to authenticated domain users, then you should be OK with setting up multiple endpoints in your web.config so that product-A and product-B can access the WCF service via separate bindings.

- Create one binding for authenticated domain users
- Create another for client certificate authentication
- In your config for product-A, use the first binding
- In your config for product-B, use the second

The following MSDN articles will give you more information on the WCF web.config and endpoint specification:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff648505.aspx